# Action creator in not dispatching an action

Tags: reactjs, redux

After several hrs of trying I have to come here...

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to dispatch my action, though I am successfully able to call my action creator.

My Action Creator in loginActions file

```
const changeForm = (newState) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CHANGE_FORM, newState });
};
```

In my component, I have imported loginActions

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    login: loginActions.loginCheck,
    changeForm: loginActions.changeForm
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

and I passing this in my form component like this

const changeForm = this.props.changeForm;

```
<Form data={data}
      changeForm={changeForm}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      btnText={"Login"}
      currentlySending={currentlySending}/>
```

Inside my  component, I am doing something like this with newState

this.props.changeForm(newState);

But this stuff in not dispatching the action. please help. Let me know if you want me to the additional info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your changeForm function get trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `mapDispatchToProps` so that you use dispatch there.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    changeForm: newState => dispatch(loginActions.changeForm(newState))
  }
}
```

And the action creator doesn't need `dispatch`.

```
const changeForm = newState => (
    { type: actionTypes.CHANGE_FORM, payload: newState }
)
```